# On click of image view on list item of list view with multiple views returning null in

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am changing image view icon on click of image View but when it returns null pointer exception error in list view.

here is my code. Please help me out from this

```
 public class SelectTagAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<TagDataModel> arrayList;
    LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    FilterSearchListener filterSearchListener;
    String selectedTag;
    TagDatabaseHelper tagDatabaseHelper;
    SelectTagActivity tagActivity;
    String tagType;
    static int AT_TAG_TYPE=1;
    static int HASH_TAG_TYPE=0;
    Holder holder=null;
    View view;

    public SelectTagAdapter(Context con,ArrayList arr,String tagType){
        this.context=con;
        this.arrayList=arr;
        this.tagType = tagType;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        tagActivity=(SelectTagActivity)context;
        tagDatabaseHelper = new TagDatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void setFilterListener(FilterSearchListener filterSearchListener) {
        this.filterSearchListener=filterSearchListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position).hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position).getViewType() ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final TagDataModel tag=new TagDataModel();
        View rowView=null;
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if(rowView==null) {
            holder =new Holder();

            switch (viewType)

            {

                case 0://For # type Tags


                    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_item_hash_type, null);
                    view = rowView;

                    holder.checked = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checked);
                    holder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tag_realtivelayout);

                    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            getTagStatus("", position, holder, HASH_TAG_TYPE,view);

                        }
                    });


                 break;



                case 1: // for @ type tags

                    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_item, null);
                    view = rowView;


                    holder.upIv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.up);
                    holder.downIv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.down);
                    holder.neutralIv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.neutral);
                    holder.exclamationIv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exclamation);


                    holder.upIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            getTagStatus("up", position, holder,AT_TAG_TYPE,view);


                        }
                    });

                    holder.downIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            getTagStatus("down", position, holder,AT_TAG_TYPE,view);


                        }
                    });

                    holder.neutralIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            getTagStatus("neutral", position, holder,AT_TAG_TYPE,view);

                        }
                    });

                    holder.exclamationIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            getTagStatus("esclamation", position, holder,AT_TAG_TYPE,view);

                        }
                    });




                    break;




            }

            holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            holder.subtitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_subtitle);

                rowView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (Holder) rowView.getTag();

        }



            holder.title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.subtitle.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSubtitle());

                if(viewType==1) {



                    if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus() != null) {
                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals("up")) {
                            holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
                        }

                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals("down")) {
                            holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                        }

                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals("neutral")) {
                            holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral);
                        }

                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals("esclamation")) {
                            holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation);
                        }

                    }
                }else
                {
                        if(arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus()!=null)
                        if(arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals("true"))
                        {
                            holder.checked.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick_icon);

                        }



                }


        return rowView;
    }

 public  static class Holder {
        TextView title,subtitle;
        ImageView upIv,downIv,neutralIv,exclamationIv,checked;
     RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new ListFilter();
    }

    public class ListFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String constraintStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();


            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<TagDataModel> filterItems = new ArrayList<TagDataModel>();

                synchronized (this) {
                    for (TagDataModel item : arrayList) {
                        if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(constraintStr)) {
                            filterItems.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    result.count = filterItems.size();
                    result.values = filterItems;
                }
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.count = arrayList.size();
                    result.values = arrayList;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filterSearchListener.UpdateFilteredResult(constraint, results.values);
        }
    }

    public interface FilterSearchListener{
        public void UpdateFilteredResult(CharSequence constraint, Object results);
    }





    public void getTagStatus(String status ,int position,Holder holder,int tagViewType,View view)
    {

        switch (tagViewType) {

            case 0:
                    if(arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus()=="true") {
                        if (tagDatabaseHelper.deleteTag(arrayList.get(position)) > 0) {
                            arrayList.remove(arrayList.get(position));
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }else
                        {
                            holder.checked.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick_icon);
                            arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus("true");
                            tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));


                        }
                        if (tagType.contains("All_Tags"))
                            tagActivity.setVisibilitySelectedTagListView();






                break;








            case 1:
            switch (status) {

                case "up":


                    selectedTag = "up";
                    if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus() != null) {
                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals(selectedTag)) {
                            if (tagDatabaseHelper.deleteTag(arrayList.get(position)) > 0) {
                                arrayList.remove(arrayList.get(position));
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        } else {

                            holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
                            holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_normal);
                            holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral_normal);
                            holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation_normal);

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                            arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);


                            tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));
                        }


                    } else {


                        holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
                        holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_normal);
                        holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral_normal);
                        holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation_normal);

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                        arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                        tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));
                    }

                    if (tagType.contains("All_Tags"))
                        tagActivity.setVisibilitySelectedTagListView();


                    break;


                case "down":


                    selectedTag = "down";

                    if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus() != null) {

                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals(selectedTag)) {
                            if (tagDatabaseHelper.deleteTag(arrayList.get(position)) > 0) {
                                arrayList.remove(arrayList.get(position));
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_normal);
                            holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                            holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral_normal);
                            holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation_normal);

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                            arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                            tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));
                        }


                    } else {
                        holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_normal);
                        holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                        holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral_normal);
                        holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation_normal);

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                        arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                        tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));
                    }
                    if (tagType.contains("All_Tags"))
                        tagActivity.setVisibilitySelectedTagListView();


                    break;


                case "neutral":


                    selectedTag = "neutral";


                    if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus() != null) {

                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals(selectedTag)) {
                            if (tagDatabaseHelper.deleteTag(arrayList.get(position)) > 0) {
                                arrayList.remove(arrayList.get(position));
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        } else {
                            **holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_normal);
                            holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_normal);
                            holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral);
                            holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation_normal);**

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                            arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                            tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));
                        }


                    } else {


                        ****holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_normal);
                        holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_normal);
                        holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral);
                        holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation_normal);

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                        arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                        tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));


                    }
                    if (tagType.contains("All_Tags"))
                        tagActivity.setVisibilitySelectedTagListView();


                    break;


                case "esclamation":


                    selectedTag = "esclamation";


                    if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus() != null) {


                        if (arrayList.get(position).getTagstatus().equals(selectedTag)) {
                            if (tagDatabaseHelper.deleteTag(arrayList.get(position)) > 0) {
                                arrayList.remove(arrayList.get(position));
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_normal);
                            holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_normal);
                            holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral_normal);
                            holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation);


                            arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                            tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));
                        }


                    } else {

                        holder.upIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_normal);
                        holder.downIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_normal);
                        holder.neutralIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral_normal);
                        holder.exclamationIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation);

                    /*tag.setId(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getId());
                    tag.setTitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getTitle());
                    tag.setSubtitle(SelectTagActivity.selectedList.get(position).getSubtitle());*/
                        arrayList.get(position).setTagstatus(selectedTag);
                        tagDatabaseHelper.addUpdateTag(arrayList.get(position));

                    }

                    if (tagType.contains("All_Tags"))
                        tagActivity.setVisibilitySelectedTagListView();


                    break;


            }

                break;


        }






    }

}
```

Here's my logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.analec.clientmanager.adapter.SelectTagAdapter.getTagStatus(SelectTagAdapter.java:369)
            at com.abc.manager.adapter.SelectTagAdapter$3.onClick(SelectTagAdapter.java:139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Code which is in bold showing null pointer exception.

Comment: There is no bold in code, better to print the exception and the lines causing it.

Comment: @SuhasB i have added logcat

Comment: @Lolmewn snippet in ** showing error

Comment: which is line it is : SelectTagAdapter.java:369

Comment: @SuhasB getTagStatus("down", position, holder, AT_TAG_TYPE); this line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)